# Try to make a preamp guitar

Tags: operational-amplifier, preamp

Hi i found this circuit in the net beacuse i want to make my preamp guitar..
I built it on my breadboard but when attach the battery, guitar doesn't make sound even if the amplificator is on... Have you any suggestion??  the circuit it's ok? or I'm wrong?

I googled a lot but i can't figure out why doesn't work...
[image: circuit]
<sub>(source: [labguitars.com](http://www.labguitars.com/images/schematic-booster1.png))</sub>

and finally I'm Italian so sorry for my bad english

Comment: What have you connected to the output?

Comment: What is the op-amp and what is R3's value?

Comment: This is a pretty standard inverting amplifier so the topology should be fine. You might want to check a few things with the circuit in isolation (i.e. nothing connected to the output). 1) Check that the input terminals are biased to about half the battery voltage. 2) The gain is \$-R_4/R_3\$ so drive the input with a sine wave and make sure the you get a sine wave at the output with the expected gain in amplitude.

Comment: It is assumed that your GND wire from the guitar output is connected to the common ground of your circuit. It would be difficult to find what's the problem with your circuit without measurements.

Comment: The circuit is okay provided the value of R3 is reasonable; you have botched the build. Also, you should bypass R1 with a capacitor. That will particularly come in handy if you go to a permanent power supply, which has more noise than batteries. How would you do that? You can power an on-board guitar pre-amp using phantom power through the instrument cable, so there is no battery in the guitar. The box on the other end of the cable (built by you) which provides phantom power obtains it from an AC adapter.

Comment: Hello everyone and thank you for feedback

=====
JohnU

The amplifier is connected to the output

====

Andyaka  

The op-amp is **tl071** and R3 change between *15 to 150 Kohm*

====
Kaz

Thanks for the tip but I think I will use a battery

====

Null
1. I have check and the input terminal are biased to half the battery voltage 
2. I haven't an oscilloscope so i can't check if i get a sine wave

Answer (score 5):

Guitar pre-amps are usually designed with a high input resistance (typically 1M0). Your circuit has an input impedance roughly equal to the value of R3 which I suspect is somewhat lower than R4 probably by a factor of 10. Even at 150k it would be too low.

[image]

A better approach would be to use a non-inverting configuration for the op-amp such as.

[image]

The gain is set by R4 and R3  (Gain = 1 + R4/R3). The pre-amp has a gain of about 3. The input impedance is about 1M1 (2 x 2m2 in parallel). It uses a FET input op amp.

Note **this is only a pre-amp**. It will **not** drive a loudspeaker or headphones. You need to take the output of this circuit into an amplifier capable of driving a speaker.

Comment: A 150K impedance could perhaps work okay if this is built into the guitar, because we do not have the capacitance of the instrument cable to deal with between the pickup and the preamp.  The inverting topology has virtues on single supply: the input is isolated form power supply noise, and the voltage reference for (+) can be well bypassed. (Less of a concern on batteries, but this type of circuit can be phantom-powered through the instrument cable!)

Comment: @Kaz The vast majority of guitar pre amps have standardised around a high impedance input (and I do go back to my days in the early 60's when I built these thing with valves.) If it was good enough approach for Fender et al its certainly good enough for me.

Comment: I understand, but I interpreted the question (perhaps wrongly) as building a "preamp guitar": guitar that has an on-board pre-amp. I just mean that if this is an on-board pre-amp on the guitar, then things are a little different because there isn't a 20 foot, capacitive cable between the pickup and the preamp. Actually, you know, it might be worth to simulate the capacitance of that cable: make the pre-amp input have the same response as an instrument cable plus normal amp, so the pickups have the same "honk" as normal. :)

Comment: @Kanz thanks I'll try to do your circuit, I want to create a preamplifier and inserting it into the guitar that I'm building

Comment: @Kaz   No problem. My interpretation of this question is that it comes from someone starting out with electronics "I found this circuit on the net" so I kept it very simple. I suspect that the original circuit would work (although not particularly well) and the reason why it didn't work was either faulty construction or trying to use it as an amplifier and drive a speaker of some sort (hence my last lines in the answer) but that's mere speculation. If I was building it into the guitar I'd probably go for a FET transistor design (nice warm sound) with phantom supply.

Comment: With the availability of phantom power, a nice buffer circuit is found in the ADA MP-1 pre-amp, where the front jack goes into an interesting circuit where an N-JFET appears to be complementary-paired with a PNP BJT; like a Sziklai pair but with a JFET and PNP, not NPN-PNP. You can see it in the upper left here (Q6, Q7): http://www.kylheku.com/mp1-files/mp1-schematics/ADA-MP1-001-027-input.jpg

Comment: @kaz - an excellent front end design (and I note R9 is 1M0 ;) ) and The +/- 15V give a lot of overhead and room for amplification. For anyone wanting to build a simpler pre-amp they could have a look at this one http://www.till.com/articles/GuitarPreamp/