# Why does my guitar pre-amp lose it's offset?

Tags: operational-amplifier, guitar-amplifier

I found a [guitar preamp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127781/try-to-make-a-preamp-guitar) on the web after trying to build one myself and having no luck. This one works for a bit, but the offset part of the OP-amp slowly depletes. It's like C1 is charging up really quickly then just discharging over time. [image]

The only differences from this circuit is that I'm using a gain of 10K/4.7K and a 100 uF electrolytic for C3, bypass capacitor. I'm also using a [MCP6002](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP6001-1R-1U-2-4-1-MHz-Low-Power-Op-Amp-DS20001733L.pdf) at 5V which isn't a FET Op-amp. Can someone please explain to me why it's not working?

Comment: R1 and R2 are a bit on the large side ... 100k for each should be fine.

Comment: For a guitar input, you need Mohm input impedance to 10 Mohm. If you don't do that you lose the top end treble response. I expect that the 100 uF is going a bit leaky and busting the DC levels.

Comment: A fault in C2, or a 9V battery venting gas, could also cause this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MCP6001-1R-1U-2-4](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP6001-1R-1U-2-4-1-MHz-Low-Power-Op-Amp-DS20001733L.pdf) datasheet specifies a few key points:

- Section 1.0 Electrical Characteristics: Input bias current is 1pA, so the opamp is essentially a JFET-input class.  Maximum output voltage swing is within 25mV of power rails, so device is also rail-to-rail output, despite it not highlighting either on the front page.
- Section 4.3 Capacitive Loads: If C4 is really 10µF (and whatever after it is a fairly low impedance), a resistor in front of C4 may help. Temporarily replace the electrolytic caps with solid ceramic ones (surface mount, value not critical) - just to see if they make a difference.
- Section 4.4 Bypass capacitors: do you have these installed?
- Section 4.5 Unused Opamps: has this been followed?
- Section 4.6 PCB surface leakage: is the board design causing leakage? Layout is important for the input. Even residual flux can cause leakage at this high impedance.

Edit: since adding the resistance before C4 helped, the issue must be that whatever is after this stage is too low of an impedance for this opamp. A solution may be to use the other amp in this package as a "unity-gain follower:"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3c88S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is still an output capacitance limitation in the "buffer" stage, but the effect may be minimal as the gain is just 1:1.

Note that C1,R1,R2 form a high-pass filter on the input; 0.1µF likely would give very little low-frequency response, so it was bumped to 1µF. Some experimentation may be needed.  Added C5 per datasheet.

Comment: Adding the resistor before C4 worked but now the gain doesn't seem to be non-existent. Changing the capacitors to ceramic seemed to have no effect. I believe the 50 uF capacitor is effectively a bypass capacitor.

Comment: I’d think twice about using hi-k ceramics in the audio chain since they tend to be piezoelectric.

Comment: True Kartman, that was just for testing - do not leave them in there. Yes, C3 is a bypass capacitor. Section 4.4 reads "the power supply pin (VDD for single supply) should have a local bypass capacitor (i.e., 0.01 µF to 0.1 µF) within 2 mm for good high-frequency performance. It also needs a bulk capacitor (i.e., 1 µF or larger) within 100 mm to provide large, slow currents."